# How to serialize Protobuf to JSON with additional fields?

Tags: java, json, protocol-buffers

In Java, I am looking for a way to serialize a protobuf object to JSON in a way that I can add some additional metadata to the output.

For example if my protobuf object looks like:

```
message ToBeSerialized {
  string value_one = 1;
  string value_two = 2;
}
```

And I want my output JSON to look like:

```
{
  "value_one": "some_value",
  "value_two": "other_value",
  "additional_field_1": "my_value",
  "additional_field_2": "my_other_value"
}
```

The JsonFormat does not appear to support my use case as there is no way to add additional/arbitrary fields to the output.

I could re-implement JsonFormat, but ew... There must be a simple way to add some additional metadata without re-implementing all that code.
I've also considered crafting a new protobuf object with the additional fields I want and using an `Any` field to store my base message, but that also seems like more work than it should take.
I'm hoping I'm overlooking something easy/obvious.

Efficiency is critical. For example writing to JSON, then reading back into a Map, adding the fields, and then re-serializing to JSON is not an option.

Comment: I suspect the *simplest* option would be to output the JSON, parse it back as a JSONObject or similar, add the extra fields, then serialize back out to JSON. It wouldn't be efficient, but it would be really simple to do. How crucial is efficiency to you?

Comment: Efficiency is critical, this approach is not an option.

Comment: Please specify that in the question then. (Are there any other restrictions which would make entirely-reasonable answers unsuitable for your purposes?)

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON type is a superset of your proto messages and (since the proto-generated classes represent the messages), a superset of the protoc-generated classes.

It is considered good practice to implement app wrappers around protoc-generated classes and this is what you should do.

These app wrappers would include the metadata and methods to/from JSON and methods to/from Protobuf class.

Even when using metadata with Protobuf requests and responses, this is always managed out-of-band of the underlying messages because, as it should, metadata is not generally part of the message that it describes.